# AS2: Get TextField true height

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, textfield

I am creating a bunch of TextFields at run-time containing `htmlText` the problem is that getting the height of the `TextField` is extremely inaccurate.

If I access the `TextField._height` or the `TextField.height` property it is not even close to accurate and can vary between 0 - 1.5 line-heights.

I have attempted to put the TextField into an empty `MovieClip` and get the MovieClip's height however that returns the same inaccuracy. (Shown in example)

**Relevant code:**

```
var format = new TextFormat();
format.size = 14;
format.align = "left";
format.font = "Arial";
format.color = 0x000000;
format.leading = 3;

var textBoxes:Array = new Array();

function createText(htmlString:String, isOption:Boolean, name:String) {
    var textY:Number;
    if(isOption) {
        var textMC:MovieClip = target.attachMovie("option", "txt_" + textBoxes.length, target.getNextHighestDepth());
        textMC.name.text = name;
    } else {
        var textMC:MovieClip = target.createEmptyMovieClip("txt_" + textBoxes.length, target.getNextHighestDepth());
    }
    var fieldContainer:MovieClip = textMC.createEmptyMovieClip("container", textMC.getNextHighestDepth());
    var textBox:TextField = fieldContainer.createTextField("textBox", fieldContainer.getNextHighestDepth(), studySettings.margin, studySettings.margin, target._width - (studySettings.margin * 2),0);
    textBox.autoSize = true;
    textBox.wordWrap = true;
    textBox.html = true;
    textBox.multiline = true;
    textBox.htmlText = htmlString;
    textBox.setTextFormat(format);
    textBox.embedFonts = true;
    textBox.selectable = false;
    textBox.antiAliasType = "advanced";
    if(isOption) {
        textMC.option = currentOption;
        textMC.enabled = false;
        textBox._y += textMC.background._y;
        textBox._width = textMC._width - (studySettings.margin * 3);
        textMC.background._width = target._width - (studySettings.margin * 2);
        textMC.background._height = fieldContainer._height + (studySettings.margin * 2);
        textMC._x = studySettings.margin;
        textMC.onRollOver = function() {
            this.background.gotoAndStop("over");
        }
        textMC.onRollOut = function() {
            this.background.gotoAndStop("up");
        }
        textMC.onRelease = function() {
            showStudy(study.caseIndex, study.choiceIndex, false, this.option);
            clearStudy(study, false);
        }
    }
    if(textBoxes.length) {
        var prebounds:Object = textBoxes[textBoxes.length - 1].getBounds(target);
        textMC._y = (isOption) ? prebounds.yMax + studySettings.margin : prebounds.yMax;
    } else {
        textMC._y = 0;
    }
    textBoxes.push(textMC);
```

How can I reliably get the `TextField` height?

Answer (score 0):

TextField.textWidth/TextField.textHeight should return the actual dimensions of the *content* of the field.

I find if you're using these measurements for layout they're not perfect, if you're scaling a TextField to the textual content it's normally best to add 10-20 to each dimension, or you get the odd character cut off - but these will return a realistic value, width/height won't reflect the dimensions.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried `textMC.background._height = textBox.textHeight + (studySettings.margin * 2)` where `studySettings.margin = 15` and is constant. Yet `textMC.background` is visually smaller than the text in `textBox`

Comment: I was actually talking about AS3 (my fault for not noticing), not used AS2 for about five years but think they're the same in this case. I do find textWidth/textHeight to be unreliable, they're never as big as the actual field itself. The other thing you can do is size the field eg TextField.width = TextField.textWidth + A_CONST_AMOUNT (you'll need to experiment), then set the textMC.background dimensions from the field. I do this to resize fields when content text is dynamic, again I normally find adding 10-20 is enough to give the text space to display.